# Аналоги template из C++ в C#

Tags: c#

Когда я решал задачу я познакомился с таким списком как List. И как я часто это делаю решил заглянуть в define-file где увидел вот это:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, IList, IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    private const int DefaultCapacity = 4;

    internal T[] _items; // Do not rename (binary serialization)
    internal int _size; // Do not rename (binary serialization)
    internal int _version; // Do not rename (binary serialization)
...
```

Ключевого слова template в C# нету, собственно откуда взялось `<T>`???

*define-file это файл где находятся функции типо Console.WriteLine(777); Делается это нажатием клавиши Control(Ctrl) и нажатием на переменную/функцию/класс в Visual Studio & Visual Studio Code.

Comment: `<T>` - это синтаксис, а не ключевое слово. Можете сами создать дженерик и написать не T а U или TU или вообще что угодно, кроме ключевых слов. Ну и еще в дженерик нельзя передать например поинтеры

Comment: Спасибо. Напиши пожалуйста вот это в ответ.

Comment: Вообще перейти к определению можно клавишей F12

Comment: Да, знаю, но     кое что случилось